# Add new rows when new value exists

Tags: google-sheets, data-entry

I have a dataset I'm importing into my spreadsheet (using ImportRange). I'm wanting to count the amount of each data value imported. So say I have a column of numbers (1 and 2), I'm wanting to count each one. But the dataset is expanding with each user input, so if someone puts a 3, I've been having to add a new row and copy my equation into that so it can handle the new value.

How can I change this so that if a new value is passed in, the spreadsheet will automatically add a new row for that value and update the values?

I'd also like it to be in numerical order if at all possible. I'm using numbers 1-999 and it's difficult to keep track of if it's not in order.

Comment: If you are using Google Sheets, you should add that tag so people won't provide Excel solutions.  Excel's import functions do that automatically.  But I have no idea about `ImportRange`

Comment: I'll go ahead and fix that tag error.  That is a little strange that you would not tag the platform you are using but do tag one your specifically not using. To answer the question, automation is how you would change that.  It would be a good idea to start with a basic tutorial on Google Sheets Macros.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your data imported is in column A. Then in column B beneath your headers place `=sort(unique(A:A))`. That will give your sorted list of values. For me the first value was in B3. So next to that I placed `=countIF(A:A,B3)`. That can be dragged down as far as you anticipate you could have values (in your case no more that 1000 rows give or take). That will show 0's beyond the end. If you want to suppress them, wrap it in `=IF(countIF(A:A,B3)=0,"",countIF(A:A,B3))` and drag that down instead.

Comment: If you have headers, you may want to make some of my A:A more like A$2:A or similar.